# How can I save a 1x1 tibble from a dataframe as a value?

Tags: r, tibble

For example I have a 5x1 dataframe and I want to loop over all the rows and I want to use the character that is in each observation and store it as a value, how can this be done? I cannot seem to circumvent it being saved as a tibble which prevents me from using said observation as a input in a function.

Comment: Please provide your code with an example of your data and your expected outcome.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear and mostly hypothetical. It will be much easier to answer (and more inline with Stack's *"Specific programming problems"*) if you provide a more reproducible (concrete) question, including sample data (i.e., provided using `data.frame`, `read.table`, or `dput`, to name three methods), expected output, and code attempted. Some good refs that discuss these in more depth: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(value = c("a", "b", "c"))

df %>%
  pluck("value", 2)
#> [1] "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>